# Redirect component angular routing

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have 2 components. 1 is the registration component, 2 is the main component. And before the main component, I need to open the register component. That is, a person visits the site link, and the register component opens for him. After registration, the main component opens.

```
RouterModule.forRoot ([
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'registration', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'registration', component: RegisterComponent }
])
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need to create 2 component:

1. Main component ("e.g: User Component")
2. Registration Component

After you create that component, you need to create 2 Guard,

1. Ensure Register Guard or Ensure authenticate guard
2. Ensure Not Register Guard or Ensure not authenticate guard

After you create 2 guard and 2 component, now you can use the first guard to main component and the second guard to registration component.

**For example you can look at here:**

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qh67uh

Preview: https://angular-ivy-qh67uh.stackblitz.io

I hope it can help.